# Plotting optimize grid heatmap results of lmfit or scipy brute method

Tags: python, matplotlib, optimization, scipy

I'm trying to optimise several functions using the brute-force method of [lmfit (based on scipy minimize)](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/). The function I'm minimizing can have a variable number of parameters passed into it (each parameter with variable optimisation range) 
I've made a simple example to demonstrate.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import lmfit

def my_fun(param): # function to be optimised
    return -1. * (.1 * param['a']**2 + 2. * param['b'] - 5. * \ 
                  param['c']**0.5 - param['d'] + param['e'])

def brute_wrapper(optimiser_parameters): 
    """ so I can optimise my_fun() across any parameter set """
    initial = {'a': 1., 'b': 2., 'c': 3., 'd': 4., 'e': 5.}
    parameters = optimiser_parameters.valuesdict()

    for key in initial.keys(): # replace parameters established in optimiser
        if key in parameters.keys():
            initial[key] = parameters[key]

    return my_fun(initial) # fitness indicator
```

I can plot the results easily if I'm only varying two parameters, like so:

```
# calculating and plotting for 2
optimisers = lmfit.Parameters()
optimisers.add("b", min=1, max=5, brute_step=1)
optimisers.add("e", min=5, max=11, brute_step=1)
brute = lmfit.minimize(brute_wrapper, optimisers, method='brute')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
x, y = brute.brute_grid
value = -1 * np.array(brute.brute_Jout)
image = ax.pcolormesh(x, y, value)
fig.colorbar(image)
ax.set_xlabel(brute.var_names[0])
ax.set_ylabel(brute.var_names[1])
plt.show()
```

[image: varying only two parameters]

but for 3 or more plots I'd like to grid up the heatmaps (one plot for each pairing (b~c, b~d, b~e, ..., d~e)) but without doubling up (see example at the end).

```
# calculating and plotting for 4
optimisers = lmfit.Parameters()
optimisers.add("b", min=1, max=5, brute_step=1)
optimisers.add("c", min=2, max=8, brute_step=1)
optimisers.add("d", min=1, max=6, brute_step=1)
optimisers.add("e", min=5, max=11, brute_step=1)
brute = lmfit.minimize(brute_wrapper, optimisers, method='brute')
# how to structure data for plot?
```

I tried to use [corner.corner](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/corner) and dissected some code from plot_mcmc() in scipy with no luck.

How do I deconstruct the data from `brute` and make such a plot?

I made a crappy picture to show what I mean (universal colour bar is a fool's hope)

[image: example crappy picture]

Comment: it seems you want to "fix c, d, explore a, b", then "fix b, d, explore a, c", then "fix b, c, explore a, d" to make the first column of the corner plot, and so on.   That is, just permute over pairs of variables, fixing the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To permute over the pairs of variables you can use the `itertools.combinations()` on the variable names (or indices if you prefer).

```
>>>list(itertools.combinations(brute.var_names, 2))
[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'd'), ('b', 'c'), ('b', 'd'), ('c', 'd')]
```

This will give you the x, y variable pairs for each plot.

You will also need to specify the [matplotlib.pyplot.subplot](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplot) position index for each plot

i.e. for 4 parameters the lower diagonal of the 3x3 grid with positions.

```
(1) (2) (3)
(4) (5) (6)
(7) (8) (9)
```

To match the order of the `combinations()` output above you need the numbers in the order [1, 4, 7, 5, 8, 9]

You can get this with with something like this...

```
def get_tril_positions(n):
    """Lower square triangular position"""
    tril_pos = np.tril((np.arange(n**2) + 1).reshape(n, -1)).T.ravel()
    return tril_pos[tril_pos != 0]
```

Where n is the number of parameters minus 1.

Assuming that for the x-y parameters you would like the minimum residual values (letting all other parameters vary) then you can collapse the brute_grid and the brute_Jout along the other axis using [np.amin()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.amin.html).

Now with the N-d array collapsed into a 2-d array you can plot it "normally" like a 2-d array.

Combing the above together I get something like.
    from itertools import combinations
    n = len(brute.var_names) - 1
    combos = list(combinations(brute.var_names, 2))
    positions = get_tril_positions(n)

```
for (xname, yname), pos in zip(combos, positions):
    # Specify subplot 
    ax = plt.subplot(n, n, pos)

    # Find index for these variables
    xi = brute.var_names.index(xname)
    yi = brute.var_names.index(yname)

    # get the meshgrids for x and y
    X = brute.brute_grid[xi]
    Y = brute.brute_grid[yi]

    # Find other axis to collapse. 
    axes = tuple([ii for ii in range(brute.brute_Jout.ndim) if ii not in (xi, yi)])

    # Collapse to minimum Jout
    min_jout = np.amin(brute.brute_Jout, axis=axes)
    min_xgrid = np.amin(X, axis=axes)
    min_ygrid = np.amin(Y, axis=axes)

    ax.pcolormesh(min_xgrid, min_ygrid, min_jout)

    # Add colorbar to each plot
    plt.colorbar()

    # Add labels to edge only 
        if pos >= n**2 - n:
        plt.xlabel(xname)
    if pos % n == 1:
        plt.ylabel(yname)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Which produces what you want.

[Corner plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34sYh.png)

Note, I did not multiply `brute_Jout` by -1 so you may need to us `np.amax` instead if you are using your `value`.

Comment: This is incredible, I had mashed together a solution but wasn't happy with it so dropped the idea. This has re-inspired me! 
Thank you, Jason

Comment: a small correction to `list(itertools.combinations([brute.var_names], 2))` should be `list(itertools.combinations(brute.var_names, 2))`