# lmfit scipy optimize method has "TypeError: brute() got an unexpected keyword argument 'workers'"

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize, lmfit

I am minimising a function test_fn() using the brute-force method of lmfit (based on scipy minimize). It is a function of 4 parameters a,b,c,d. The edited code I use is below:

```
def test_fn(param): # example function to be optimised
    return param['a']+ param['b']+param['c']+param['d'] + param['e']

def brute_wrapper(optimiser_parameters): 
    """ so I can optimise test_fn() across any parameter set """

    initial = {'a': 1., 'b': 2., 'c': 3., 'd': 4., 'e': 5.}
    parameters = optimiser_parameters.valuesdict()

    for key in initial.keys(): # replace parameters established in optimiser
        if key in parameters.keys():
            initial[key] = parameters[key]

    return test_fn(initial) # fitness indicator


optimisers = lmfit.Parameters()
optimisers.add("b", min=1, max=5, brute_step=1)
optimisers.add("c", min=2, max=8, brute_step=1)
optimisers.add("d", min=1, max=6, brute_step=1)
optimisers.add("e", min=5, max=11, brute_step=1)
brute = lmfit.minimize(brute_wrapper, optimisers, method='brute')
```

When I try to run this, though, it returns:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-138-70999d7bb08c> in <module>()
---> 12 brute = lmfit.minimize(brute_wrapper, optimisers, method='brute')`

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/lmfit/minimizer.py in minimize(self, method, params, **kws)
   2361                         val.lower().startswith(user_method)):
   2362                     kwargs['method'] = val
-> 2363         return function(**kwargs)
   2364 
   2365 

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/lmfit/minimizer.py in brute(self, params, Ns, keep, workers, max_nfev)
   1941         result.call_kws = brute_kws
   1942         try:
-> 1943             ret = scipy_brute(self.penalty, tuple(ranges), **brute_kws)
   1944         except AbortFitException:
   1945             pass

TypeError: brute() got an unexpected keyword argument 'workers'
```

adding `workers=1` to the arguments returns the same error.

This is inspired from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49015138/plotting-optimize-grid-heatmap-results-of-lmfit-or-scipy-brute-method) which does not seem to produce this error, so was wondering if it might be a bug or a change in any updates that has not been well documented.

Comment: Which version of SciPy do you have installed?  From Python, you can check by running `import scipy; print(scipy.__version__)`.  The `workers` parameter was added to `brute`  in SciPy version 1.3.0.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I had version 1.2.1, upgrading scipy resolved this, thanks!!!!!!!!

Comment: For reference, the latest `lmfit` requires `scipy>1.6`, so that would suggest you had a pretty old version.  That is, upgrading `lmfit` might be wise too.